# Verifying the value of double integral obtained by NIntegrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I want to calculate this integral -

$I = \int\limits_1^\infty\int\limits_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{q(x+y+0.2+v)/(k*T)}}\right) \left(\frac{1}{e^{q(-x-y-0.2)/(k*T)}+1}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\right) dy dx -  \int\limits_1^\infty\int\limits_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{q(-x-y-0.2-v)/(k*T)}}\right) \left(\frac{1}{e^{q(x+y+0.2)/(k*T)}+1}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\right) dy\ dx$

Where k = 1.38*10^-23

T = 300

q = 1.6*10^-19

I used the following code :

> q := 1.6*10^-19 ;
>
> k := 1.38*10^-23;
>
> T = 300;
>
> f[v_?NumericQ] := (NIntegrate[(1/(1 + 
>             Exp[(q*(x + y + 0.2 + v))/(k*T)]))*(1/(Exp[(
>              q*(-x - y - 0.2))/(k*T)] + 1))*(1/Sqrt[y]), {y, 0, 
>         Infinity}, {x, 1, Infinity}] - 
>       NIntegrate[(1/(1 + 
>             Exp[(q*(-x - y - 0.2 - v))/(
>              k*T)]))*(1/(Exp[((x + y + 0.2)*q)/(k*T)] + 1))*(1/
>           Sqrt[y]), {y, 0, Infinity}, {x, 1, Infinity}]);
>
> LogPlot[-f[v], {v, 0, 1}]

The order of magnitude of f which I get is 10^(-23), which I suspect is wrong. Is there a way to verify that the numerical integration done by NIntegrate is right?

Comment: Use exact inputs (e.g., 1/2 instead of .5) and then increase the `WorkingPrecision` used in `NIntegrate`. If the results converge, you can really on the `NIntegrate` output.

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite understand what exact inputs mean in my equation. Also, can you tell me how to include WorkPrecision in here?